# Homeomorphism between open convex set and unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove that every open convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to a unit ball. I found this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3050646/584860.

The two answers in the question are essentialy the same. I cannot understand the extension of inverse map. Specifically, in the second answer, I would like that someone could explain to me how the function $f$ works for $x \in int A\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Extending the homeomorphismto the interior]

Here's a sketch. The idea is that the origin, $f(y)$ and $y / \|y\|$ should be in the same proportions as the origin, $y$, and $\eta(y)$ (all viewed as points on the ray emanating from the origin in the direction of $y$). Symbolically this is saying that we should have
$$\frac{\|f(y)\|}{\left\|\frac{y}{\|y\|} \right\|}  = \frac{\|y\|}{\|\eta(y)\|},$$
as you can check holds.